# Having dropdowns within dropdowns in Python Dash Framework

Tags: python, dropdown, plotly-dash, dashboard

I want to create a dropdown using dash.dcc (in Python) such that it renders new dropdowns on hovering over/selecting any options in the existing dropdown. For instance, this is how the current dropdown looks like =>

```
dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="living-things",
    options=[
        
        {"label": "tigers", "value": "tigers"},
        {"label": "lions", "value": "lions"},
        {"label": "pigeons", "value": "pigeons"},
        {"label": "swans", "value": "swans"},    ],
    placeholder="Select creature",
    multi=False,
)
```

What I want is to create a dropdown that shows two options => Animals and Birds. On selecting Animals, it should open another dropdown which shows tigers and lions. Similarly, on selecting Birds, it should open another dropdown which shows pigeons and swans. I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
dropdown = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="living-things",
    options=[
        {"label": "Animals", "options":[
            {"label": "tigers", "value": "tigers"},
            {"label": "lions", "value": "lions"}
        ] },
        {"label": "Birds", "options":[
            {"label": "pigeons", "value": "pigeons"},
            {"label": "swans", "value": "swans"}
        ] },  ],
    placeholder="Select creature",
    multi=False,
)
```

If dcc.Dropdown doesn't work, can we have anything alternative dropdown framework that is compatible with Dash(Python) that can facilitate this. Thanks!